# SSIS: Multiple Sources to One Destination table

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, data-warehouse

I am new SSIS & ETL. And trying to extract & load data into single destination table in sql server.
I have 4 sources - text file, csv file, excel file and some data in sql server. Please find the pictures attached that I have done so far. In one package, I have created 2 data flows, not connected (highlighted in red color boxes): one for .txt & .csv files and another for .xls & data in sql server.

Data is getting inserted but not in correct way. Here are the screenshots attached:

[image]

And the screenshot for output in destination table is shown below: Customer_ID is the auto increment.

[image]

Can anyone please let me know what am I missing and how to do it in correct way.

Thanks in advance
Raj

Comment: Looks like your join keys are not performing as expected. Glancing through the exposed fields, I cannot imagine what the expected keys would be

Comment: Thank you. In both of the Merge Joins, I have made Inner Join on Last_Name.

Comment: That will be a case sensitive match so Roberts will not match roberts. It will also be fraught with inaccurate matches as Julia Roberts will also match Tanya Roberts.

Answer (score 0):

With the example, it seems that the merges join are not working.
Are you sure that the joining columns are ok?

If not, you can try to add derived columns to format the data for each source. SSIS is case sensitive and if you work with varchar columns be careful of: start and end Space, unicode and non-unicode columns, accent, ...

Comment: Thank you. I checked joins and think they are Ok. I made inner joins on Last_name. At this moment, I would like to extract data & put it into single destination table; something like staging table.